# Implementing cross-cutting concerns in F#

Tags: f#

Does it make sense to leverage Railway-Oriented Programming techniques for cross-cutting concerns of an F# application?

For example, I am preparing for my next [kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-2/) that requires logging. As I attempt to think functional, I can't help but wonder if the patterns used in [Railway-Oriented Programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) can also be leveraged for logging function calls.

What I don't want are side-effects within my functions that are a result of managing cross-cutting concerns (i.e. logging, security, etc.).

Is there any guidance available for implementing logging behavior within F#?

Can Aspect-Oriented Programming be considered?

Comment: See: [Computation expressions: Introduction](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/)

Comment: I find it a tad contradictive to write functional arithmetics and implement logging – as in "Every time you call (...)". This looks like an inherently imperative idea. A functional calculator might think in terms of intermediate results, expression trees, or some other abstraction that is defined by its content rather than order of execution. In any real-world task, I'd either use a concept that is more closely related to the content of the operation, or use imperative features and log as a side-effect, but not try to emulate the latter with the former.

Comment: In F#, it makes sense to use function composition for logging: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/11/30/to-log-or-not-to-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it make sense to leverage Railway-Oriented Programming techniques
>   for cross-cutting concerns of an F# application?

The term Railway-Oriented Programming is one I have not heard of before but [Computation Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) and [Continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) are. Since that is such a broad question the answer is the typical it depends. I gave you the touch points so you will have to make the call.

> Can Railway-Oriented Programming (think Computation expressions) be leveraged for logging function calls?
>   Is there any guidance available for implementing logging behavior within F#?

Sure. See: [Computation expressions: Introduction](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/) which gives a logging example.

> Can Aspect-Oriented Programming be considered?

I have never used AOP so take this with a grain of salt but here is an answer from a what I consider a reliable source:

From [AOP with F#](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/10/aop-with-f-memorization-using-higher-order-functions/)

> In gen­eral, I don’t feel AOP is as well suited to func­tional pro­gram­ming as it is to object ori­ented pro­gram­ming, but there’s still a pocket of use cases where AOP can be ben­e­fi­cial.

Again this is such a broad question the answer is the typical it depends.

As a person [new to F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34655981/1243762) I would recommend that you concentrate on getting the code to work first. You are pilling on too many requirements that will just get in the way. When I started learning F# I too read too much and tried too many things with some of the best advice I received here being not to use certain things just because I could.

Comment: @ Guy Coder : will you by any chance be at NDC London next week?

Comment: Railway-Oriented Programming is a term that Scott Wlaschin uses to explain the Either monad, while avoiding the use of the word "monad" as it tends to scare functional-programming newbies away. More here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/

Comment: @rmunn Thanks, I appreciate the history. I don't know why people avoid the word "[monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))" when it is not to be avoided. The problem I find with the word "monad" is everyone scaring people before they explain it. It is like someone who could not explain it started a bad trend and now we are stuck with it. Of note, F# uses Computation Expressions which are related to monads, but they are different and one should not use the word "monad" when using talking about Computation Expressions expect to make a touch point.

Comment: @GuyCoder - Well, my own experience is the opposite of what you just said. When I was first looking into Haskell, I was *not* told "Oh, monads are a scary thing, don't worry about them." Result: I Googled monads, found that Wikipedia article which left me *hopelessly* lost and confused, and gave up on learning Haskell for a year. I think Scott Wlaschin's "Don't mention monads until after newbies have learned the concepts behind them" approach is the right way to go, because that would have been a much better learning experience for me than what actually happened.

Comment: @rmunn I can see your point. I learned Prolog while in school and when I compare monads with the Prolog programming it makes more sense. What I am hoping for but will never see is that all introductions to monads start with a good easy to understand introduction. The problem is there are so many scary introductions out there that one has to look hard to find a good one. I would write an intro but since I have so much history with them I would probably gloss over too much and make another bad intro.

Comment: I am interested in the linked question "How to make the transition to functional programming?", unfortunately the link is dead.

Comment: @bara The community [deleted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) the question on the other site. The link is not dead and the answer is still there, however with the question being deleted, only certain people like me who wrote the answer can still see it. I flagged it for moderator attention. Hopefully they will restore it.

Comment: @bara The moderator decided to remove the link in this answer rather than un-delete the question on the other site. :(

Comment: For those with the right access the deleted link is: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145866/how-to-make-the-transition-to-functional-programming/145874#145874. The answer is still there, IIRC you will need 10,000 points on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com to see it.